# Django RequestFactory; TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument;

Tags: python, django, django-tests

In attempting to test the context of a view `PostedQuestionPage` with RequestFactory, the following error is being raised when running the test:

```
  File "C:\Users\..\django\test\testcases.py", line 1201, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  Fi..\posts\test\test_views.py", line 334, in setUpTestData
    cls.view = PostedQuestionPage.as_view()(request)
  File "C:\..\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\..\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'question_id'
```

It's unclear to me as to why the error is being raised while `question_id` is being passed into `reverse("posts:question", kwargs={'question_id': 1})`?

*test_views.py*

```
class TestQuestionIPAddressHit(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a page hit is recorded from a user of a given IP address
    on a posted question.'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        user_author = get_user_model().objects.create_user("ItsNotYou")
        user_me = get_user_model().objects.create_user("ItsMe")
        author_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user_author)
        user_me = Profile.objects.create(user=user_me)
        question = Question.objects.create(
            title="Blah blahhhhhhhhh blahhh I'm bord blah blah zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
            body="This is zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...zzzzz",
            profile=author_profile
        )
        authenticated_user = user_me.user
        request = RequestFactory().get(
            reverse("posts:question", kwargs={"question_id": 1}),
            headers={
                "REMOTE_ADDR": "IP Address here"
            }
        )
        request.user = authenticated_user
        cls.view = PostedQuestionPage.as_view()(request)
```

*views.py*

```
class PostedQuestionPage(Page):

    template_name = "posts/question.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['answer_form'] = AnswerForm
        return context

    def get(self, request, question_id):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
        if question.profile.user != request.user and not question.visible:
            raise Http404
        context |= {
            'question': question,
            'answer_count': question.answers.count()
        }

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

*urls.py*

```
posts_patterns = ([
    path("", pv.QuestionListingPage.as_view(), name="main"),
    re_path(r"questions/ask/?$", pv.AskQuestionPage.as_view(), name="ask"),
    re_path(r"questions/(?P<question_id>\d+)/edit/?$", pv.EditQuestionPage.as_view(), name="edit"),
    re_path(r"questions/(?P<question_id>\d+)/edit/answers/(?P<answer_id>\d+)/?$", pv.EditPostedAnswerPage.as_view(), name="answer_edit"),

    re_path(r"questions/(?P<question_id>\d+)/?$", pv.PostedQuestionPage.as_view(), name="question"),

    re_path(r"questions/tagged/(?P<tags>[0-9a-zA-Z\.\-#]+(?:\+[0-9a-zA-Z\.\-#]+)*)$", pv.TaggedSearchResultsPage.as_view(), name="tagged"),
    re_path(r"questions/tagged/$", pv.SearchTaggedRedirect.as_view(), name="tagged_redirect"),
    re_path(r"questions/search/$", pv.SearchMenuPage.as_view(), name="search_menu"),
    re_path(r"questions/search$", pv.SearchResultsPage.as_view(), name="search_results"),
    re_path(r"questions/?$", pv.AllQuestionsPage.as_view(), name="main_paginated"),
```